# psql set default statement_timeout as a user in postgres

Tags: postgresql, timeout

I want to set a default `statement_timeout` for my access to a postgres database. After configuring my environment variables, I now have it where `psql` logs me on my preferred database and table. However, while I'm exploring several of tables in it, I'd like to have a statement timeout of around a minute. This can be done simply by typing `SET statement_timeout TO '1min';` at the beginning of each session, but this is obnoxious to type every time. I  don't have access to the server configuration nor would I want to change it. Ideally I could do something to the effect of `alias psql='psql -c "SET statement_timeout TO '1min';"' except the`-c` flag of psql doesn't allow interactive input. Are there any nice solutions to this problem, or am I always doomed to set the timeout manually for each interactive session?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could use your `.psqlrc` file (if you don't have one in your home directory, create it; if you're on `Windows` instead of `*nix`, the file is  **%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf** instead) and set the following command:

```
set statement_timeout to 60000; commit;
```

That setting is in milliseconds, so that'll set the timeout to 1 minute. `.psqlrc` isn't used with `-c` nor `-X` invocations of `psql`, so that should allow you to get your interactive-mode timeout to 1 minute.

You can then execute the following in `psql` to verify that the configuration has taken effect:

```
show statement_timeout;
```

Comment: I didn't know about .psqlrc! On my version of psql (8.4.5) it doesn't count `set [...]` as a transaction, and so complained about `commit` with `psql:~/.psqlrc:1: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress`. Otherwise it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Ah yes, the wackiness of 8.4.x... I still have to use that version sometimes and am annoyed by what isn't in it yet or how it behaves differently. =)

Comment: This is certainly off topic by now, but 8.4.x frustration was my catalyst for setting up an ssh tunnel.

Comment: v11 (1) commit no longer needed. (2) Can now specific '1min'. HINT:  Valid units for this parameter are "ms", "s", "min", "h", and "d".

Answer (score 46):

Postgres allows you to set configuration parameters such as statement_timeout on a per-role (user) level.

```
ALTER ROLE <your-username> SET statement_timeout = '60s';
```

This change will apply to all new sessions for that user, starting on the next login.

Source: [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html)

Comment: this is by far the best solution

Comment: you saved my day. thank you. again this is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a client that uses `libpq` under the hood (most of them except  Java and .NET, I think), you can use the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable.

```
export PGOPTIONS="-c statement_timeout=7200000"
```

If you're using the URI-type connection string, you can add options to the `options` URI parameter in the same format, as long as they're properly uri encoded (percent encoding)

```
psql "postgres://user:pass@server-hostname/db_name?options=-c%20statement_timeout%3D3600000
```

When using keyword-value connection strings, you can specify options like this (single quotes required)

```
psql "host=server-hostname user=user dbname=db_name options='-c statement_timeout=3600000'"
```

Additionally, the Connection Service File (`~/.pg_service.conf`) may be useful and follows the same conventions as the above config. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html

- libpq environment variables https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/libpq-envars.html
- URI parameter information https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS
- keyword-value documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING-KEYWORD-VALUE