# PostgreSQL OLEDB provider timeout error being silently ignored

Tags: c#, postgresql, oledb

I have being working on the issue for a while and here is the scenario I'm using to force the connection to timeout:

In PostgreSQL I've changed the **postgres.conf** to have its time out set to 10 millisecond.

```
statement_timeout = 10
```

And here is the code that matters:

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
var dt = new DataTable();
var result = da.Fill(dt);
```

And here is the content of the connection string:

```
"Provider=PGNP.1;Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=****;Data Source=localhost;Extended Properties=\"SSL=allow;\""
```

When the timeout occurs, no errors or exceptions are being thrown and the `dt.Rows.Count` shows **0** as the result.

When I change the postgres.conf file back to `statement_timeout = 0` (disabling it) the result of the `dt.Rows.Count` is greater than **0**.

And telling the user that he had "no results" when he actually got a timeout error is just too bad.

Any ideas?

Comment: As per [PGSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html) *Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.* Also check this thread to set [this conf at user level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092463/psql-set-default-statement-timeout-as-a-user-in-postgres). Isn't 10ms too small?

Comment: Hi @Nimesh, the reason I've set the connection to 10ms it's because I need to force a timeout to replicate the bug, it's not like that in production. But I wonder why the timeout error is not being showed. Instead, I get a successful result with 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres OLEDB provider returns a timeout error. It should result in throwing exception from the Fill method. If it does not, it could be a bug.

You can increase the timeout in Extended Propeties, e.g.: COMMAND_TIMEOUT=900; to make it 15 minutes. It will affect all queries in current OLEDB session.

Comment: Hi @Terry, some clients might experience connection timeout and that's why I had to force it in my development environment. But I think you are write, that might be a bug.